# Realm 0.92.3 Swift does not have member named objectWhere

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, realm

I am using Pods in Objective C for Realm and Swift for the front end. I can run this code in Obj-C

```
 RLMResults *xxx = [PortfolioList objectsWhere:@"object_id = %@", portfolio.object_id];
 PortfolioList *list = (PortfolioList *)xxx.firstObject;
 NSLog(@"++++News: %@", list.news);
```

but not in Swift environment

```
let ppp:RLMResults! = PortfolioList.objectsWhere("object_id = %@", self.portfolio.object_id)
var list = ppp.firstObject as! PortfolioList
println("+++++\(list.news)")
```

I am getting error

```
PortfolioList.Type does not have member named objectWhere
```

Is there an alternative ways to achieve the same result? PortfolioList has properties PortfolioNews (RLMArray)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a file "RLMSupport.swift" that you need to include beside the framework to have access to the `objectWhere` method. You find it in the Swift folder.

Answer (score 0):

That will solve the problem

```
let ppp:RLMResults! = PortfolioList.objectWhere("object_id = \(self.portfolio.object_id)")

var list = ppp.firstObject as! PortfolioList
println("+++++\(list.news)")
```

Comment: Thanks but it can't worked. I have attached an image

Answer (score -1):

You've got typo: `objectsWhere` and `objectWhere`.

Comment: It is just a typo. There is no objectsWhere for the RLMObject in Swift.

Comment: According to [source](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/4aebb18a72abc06f9735587f1e270a137e919d6a/Realm/Swift/RLMSupport.swift#L23) there's such method.

Comment: yes. I know. it can be referred in my Obj-C environment but not Swift.

Comment: Why do you need objectsWhere? Realm documentation tells to use something like this: `Realm().objects(PortfolioList).filter("object_id = %@", self.portfolio.object_id)`. [Source.](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries)

Comment: I am using **OBJ-C** Realm and not Realm Swift due to Swift only support iOS 8 and above. Thank you.